# CKEditor uncaught type error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am trying to run

```
CKEDITOR.instances.textareaid.setReadOnly(true);
```

or

```
CKEDITOR.instances["textareaid"].setReadOnly(true);
```

I get an error in the console saying

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setReadOnly' of `undefined`

However if I run the same statements in the console, it executes without error.

If I put a debugger before the statements and inspect the CKEDITOR object, the instance is present, still it throws the error.

Comment: What's your dom element where you binding ckeditor?

Comment: its looks like that your editor instance is not rendered when you are calling these scripts.

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237093/ckeditor-readonly

Comment: @rahul i have edited my answer, take a look , there you will find the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Try this sample](https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/readonly.html)
https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/readonly.html
This is may be that your ckeditor is not fully loaded. below event fires once the editor is fully loaded, so is probably where you would like to tie into. try this may be this will help u

```html
if ( CKEDITOR.status == 'loaded' ) {
    // The API can now be fully used.
     CKEDITOR.instances["textareaid"].setReadOnly(true);
}
   // Or 
CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function(event)
{
   CKEDITOR.instances["textareaid"].setReadOnly(true);
});
```

Comment: did this `console.log(CKEDITOR.status); CKEDITOR.instances.textareaid.prototype.setReadOnly(true);`

got `loaded` and `same error`

Comment: http://nightly.ckeditor.com/18-01-11-07-04/full/samples/ here is the sample for ckeditor, here open inspect element->console->console.log(CKEDITOR.status); you will get the result as loaded